# Combine v-html property with tag in vue-i18n label

Tags: laravel-5, internationalization, vuejs2

In my laravel 5.6/vue.js 2.5.7 / vue-i18n 7.8 I want to show language label with html tag, like :

```
'votes_with_rating'           => 'votes {related_votes_count} with rating `<b>{calc_artist_rating}</b>`',
```

and in vue file with computed:

```
...
computed: {

    votes_with_rating_value: function () {
        return this.$tc( 'artist.votes_with_rating', { related_votes_count : this.artist.related_votes_count, calc_artist_rating:
            this.calcArtistRating(this.artist.related_votes_count, this.artist.related_votes_sum, 1)} );
    },
...
```

But the result is different I expected, as numbers are not rendered:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5dL5.jpg
If not to use

```
<span v-html
```

then the output is valid...
Which is the right way?
Thanks!